sharex and imshow do not produce plots of the same width
Context: I have the x,y and x,z projection of an image. I want the two images to be stacked vertically sharing the same width.
My trial: I tried the following:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N1, N2 = 256, 512
table1 = np.random.rand(N1, N1)
table2 = np.random.rand(N1, N2)

f, axes = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)                                                                                                            
axes[0].imshow(table1.T,extent = [0, N1, 0, N1])
axes[1].imshow(table2.T,extent = [0, N1, 0, N2])

The wrong result: Note that  axes[0] and axes[1] share the same X-extent and the same number of pixels in the x axis, and since I used sharex=True. Therefore one would expect the example below to stack the two images vertically with the same width. Howver this is not the case. This is what I find:

You can see that the second image is smaller, however, I stress, the two have the same x-extent and same number of pixels in the x axis.
So my question is: how to stack vertically two images with same extent and pixels in the x-axis (however I need the number of pixels in y axis to possibly vary)
Why not use aspect='auto'? One may think that just adding aspect=auto will solve the issue. While the images will end with the same width, they will also have the same heigth. However the second image has a larger y-extent (and twice the pixels in the y axis). I want the images to not be stretched so to preserve their aspect ratio.

It will stretch the images however, and break the correct aspect ratio. As I said they come form the projection of a image so I want the pictures to look with the right aspect ratio. I updated the question accordingly.

The alternative is providing more space for the lower subplot. Something like f, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[2, 3]}). The exact values depend on N1 and N2, and on the space needed at the top and bottom.

Seems like a job for ImageGrid:

API docs
User Guide

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

N1, N2 = 256, 512
table1 = np.random.rand(N1, N1)
table2 = np.random.rand(N1, N2)

f = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(f, 111, nrows_ncols=(2, 1), axes_pad=0)
grid[0].imshow(table1.T)
grid[1].imshow(table2.T)

plt.show()



In your example when you run table1.T and table2.T in imshow the length of your x-axis is not the same for each matrix since you are transposing (shape goes from (256,521) -> (512, 256) for table2). However, even with the x-axis length being the same I could not get the imshow plots to align.
There are two solutions below that you could use.
You can use pcolormesh instead of imshow if you are trying to plot a matrix and not an image with RGB. Pcolormesh has better properties for plotting will behave more like a simple matplotlib plot.
f, axes = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)                                                                                  
axes[0].pcolormesh(table1.T)
# Don't transpose data so coordinates are the same when sharex=True
axes[1].pcolormesh(table2)

or
f, axes = plt.subplots(2)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0)                                                                                  
axes[0].pcolormesh(table1.T)
axes[1].pcolormesh(table2)


For imshow you need to set the extent for each plot with the same values if you want the data in the plots to fill the same size. However, the axis numbering will not represent the actual dimensions of the data underneath. The data axis is rescaled to fit the extent of the bounding box. The data coordinates on the axes will be off so you will have to relabel the ticks.
axes[0].imshow(table1.T, extent = [0, N1, 0, N2])
axes[1].imshow(table2.T, extent = [0, N1, 0, N2])

Lastly, the sharex=True will just extend the bounding box of the shortest data axis with both pcolormesh and imshow. If you leave out the extent argument of imshow or use pcolormesh and keep sharex=True in your code, you will see the extended bounding box with no data in it.
